# Python Pandas <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at ...>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to group and count the same info in a row:

```
#Functions

def postal_saude ():
    global df, lista_solic

    #List of solicitantes in Postal Saude
    list_sol = [lista_solic["name1"], lista_solic["name2"]]

    #filter Postal Saude Solicitantes
    df = df[(df['Cliente']==lista_clientes["6"]) 
        & (df['Nome do solicitante'].isin(list_sol))]

    #Alphabetical order
    df = df.sort_index(by=['Nome do solicitante', 'nomeCorrespondente'])

    #Grouping data of column
    grouping = df.groupby('Tipo do serviços');

    print (grouping)


postal_saude()
```

When it gets to the **df.groupby** it raises an error

I have tried searching this same error but I have not found a valid answer to help me fix my problem.

Comment: That's not an error, just a representation of the groupby object. You just need to apply an aggregation operation to the object to return a DataFrame or Series. There's more information about this in the docs on groupby.

Comment: I might be using the wrong command then... I'd like to simply combine all multiple rows into one

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html
combina all "foo" for example. I though i could use .groupby.... but i returns me that message

Comment: The important thing to understand is that a `groupby` object is just an object that contains metadata about how to perform the `groupby`, you have to do something with the `groupby` object such as some form of aggregation in order to return a `dataframe` or `series`

Comment: Which error is raised? Possibly something like `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000001DEA1BA4608>`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at this documentation about [Group By](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

> Group series using mapper (dict or key function, apply given function
>   to group, return result as series) or by a series of columns

The previous is taken from [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Here's a quick example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],'b':np.random.randn(10)})

df
   a         b
0  1  1.048099
1  1 -0.830804
2  1  1.007282
3  2 -0.470914
4  2  1.948448
5  2 -0.144317
6  3 -0.645503
7  3 -1.694219
8  3  0.375280
9  3 -0.065624

groups = df.groupby('a')

groups # Tells you what "df.groupby('a')" is, not an error
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000000097EEB38>

groups.count() # count the number of 1 present in the 'a' column
   b
a   
1  3
2  3
3  4

groups.sum() # sums the 'b' column values based on 'a' grouping

          b
a          
1  1.224577
2  1.333217
3 -2.030066
```

You get the idea, you can build from here using the first link I provided.

```
df_count = groups.count()

df_count
   b
a   
1  3
2  3
3  4

type(df_count) # assigning the `.count()` output to a variable create a new df
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Comment: Awesome!!!  thank you so much for the explanation, the example with comments really helped!

Comment: is there a way i can save the **count()** from the groupby to use it later?   that is exactly what i am trying to achieve

Comment: For data saving, pickles can be used easily. But in this case, I would recommend something like `df_count.to_csv("ds_count.csv", index=False)`