# Python groupby returning single value between carets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Long time listener first time caller. I am new to Python, about 3 days into this and I cannot figure out for the life of me, what is happening in this particular instance.

I brought in an XLSX file as a dataframe called dfInvoice. I want to use groupby on two columns (indexes?) but something funky is happening I think. I can't see my new grouped dataframe with the code below.

```
uniqueLocation = dfInvoice.groupby(['Location ID','Location'])
```

When I call uniqueLocation, all that is returned is this:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000001B9A1C61198>
```

I have two questions from here.

1) what the heck is going on? I followed these steps almost identically to this (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-groupby).

2) this string of text between the carets, what should I refer to this as? I didn't know how to search for this happening because I don't exactly understand what this return is.

Comment: It may sound silly, but `groupby()` returns a groupby object. You need to decide what to do with that object. For example, `dfInvoice.groupby(['Location ID', 'Location'])['total_amount'].sum()` gives you the sum of the invoice amounts for each location.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440640/python-pandas-pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-object-at.

Comment: Also: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html.

Comment: @QuangHoang so is this saying that there always has to be some sort of aggregate to get groupby to work? I guess my follow up would be why the geeks for geeks example worked the way I would expect it to?

Comment: In the link, they do `go.first()`, which is also a sort of aggregation.

Comment: @QuangHoang Actually you know what. I see now the geeks for geeks page does pull information based on a command like .first().