# How do i make a data that is using .count()) become a new pandas data table

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, count

I saw before how you can count age from this page of stack overflow, but how do i make data that has been processed into another column.

```
 age_data_array_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Age':age_data_list_1})
 bins = [0, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 110]
 age_labels = ['Less than 20', '20 years', '30 years', '40 years', '50 years', 'more_than_60']
 age_data_array_1['Age_Group'] = pd.cut(age_data_array_1['Age'], bins=bins, labels=age_labels, right = False)
 age_data_array_1['Age_Group'] = age_data_array_1['Age_Group'].cat.add_categories('invalid').fillna('invalid')
 divide_by_age_group = age_data_array_1.groupby('Age_Group')
 print(divide_by_age_group.count())
```

How do i make the divide_by_age_group.count()) become a new pandas data

[Python Pandas <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at ...>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440640/python-pandas-pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-object-at)

Comment: Do you want the groupby data as a column in the original DataFrame? Or a new DataFrame?

Comment: i need a new dataframe for it

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding your question but don't you just need:

```
df_count = divide_by_age_group.count()
```

Comment: but its not a new table if i just make that

Comment: `df_count` will be a new table with just one column but isn't that what you want?. What are you expecting to be in this new table? Are you hoping to join this aggregated column to the original table?

Answer (score 0):

turns out its as easy as
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(divide_by_age_group)